# Prevent NPE: accessing private object from another class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, encapsulation

I've declared a private variable in one class that I want to access in another. But the problem is that when I pass the object `flappyBird`, it is null. What change do I need to make, so that it isn't?

**FlappyBird.java : object created here**

```
public class FlappyBird implements ActionListener, KeyListener, MouseListener
{

    private static FlappyBird flappyBird;

    public static void main(String[] args)
        /* CREATE INSTANCE OF FLAPPBIRD() */
    {
        flappyBird = new FlappyBird();
    }

    public static FlappyBird getBird() {
        return flappyBird;
    }

    public static void paint(Graphics phics) {
        ...
    }
```

**GraphicRenderer.java : access object here**

```
    public class GraphicsRenderer extends JPanel
    {
        private static FlappyBird bird = new FlappyBird();

    public void paint(Graphics phics)
    {
        // Generate game graphics by calling paint() in FlappyBird.
        bird.getBird();
        super.paint(phics); 
        bird.paint(phics);
    }
}
```

Comment: You do understand there is no method called `getBird()` and your `setBird`/other parts are extremely wrong and don't make sense

Comment: @AndrewL my bad, I didn't type that right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes are very wrong. There is not a getter and many parts don't make sense. Here is a list of what's wrong with the code:

- No setter so the field would always be null
- For some reason, a field for instantiation
- You don't implement the methods from the interfaces you implement. I will not fix that here but you implement it yourself
- FlappyBird class has no method `paint()`. I also won't address this hear because you can do that yourself and you don't provide any details regarding the method

Here are some fixes:

```
public class FlappyBird implements ActionListener, KeyListener, MouseListener {

    private static FlappyBird flappyBird;

    public FlappyBird(/* Some attributes to the bird */) {
        /* Field = attribute */
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        flappyBird = new FlappyBird(/* Constructor Args */);
    }

    public FlappyBird getBird() {
        return flappyBird;
    }

    public void setBird(/* You decide the arguments */) {
        /* Field = argument */
    }
}
```

I added a constructor, fixed the above code, added a setter. The constructor is called like this:

```
FlappyBird fb = new FlappyBird(arguments);
```

Now, when calling, you need to instantiate and call constructor. Then, you can access the methods. I stored the `getBird()` return value in `b` and `fb` as an instance. You can extend off this code.

```
public class GraphicsRenderer extends JPanel {

    public void paint(Graphics phics) {
        FlappyBird fb = new FlappyBird(/*Args*/);
        FlappyBird b = fb.getBird();
        fb.setBird(/*Args*/);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate you trying to help me, and your extensive answer is. 1 quetsion, what do you mean by "You don't implement the methods from the interfaces you implement" ?

Comment: You implement ActionListener, KeyListener, and MouseListener. I was pointing out that you need to implement the methods from the interface, such as `actionPerformed()`, etc. If I did help, please consider accepting :^)

Comment: Oh I see. I just left the implementations and some other stuff out because I didn't think it related. And I haven't completely solved the NPE yet, but I may as well accept your answer seeing that it has helped a lot.

Comment: Thanks! If you need anything, I'll be glad to help

Comment: No problem, this is a QnA site after all :)